# QGIS atlas layout not clipping as expected

Tags: qgis, atlas

Using QGIS 3.24.3-Tisler. I've created an atlas that seems to partially work. The "basemap" layers successfully clip, but several of the other layers do not. It seems to be an all or nothing situation. If I select the layer under "Clip selected layers," then everything disappears. If I leave the layer un-selected, then it shows content outside the desired bounds. Am I misunderstanding how the Atlas feature works? I assumed that it was clipping based on geometry.

Not Clipped
[image: Not Clipped]

Clipped
[image: Clipped]

Comment: That's really strange. I thought it might perhaps be a CRS mismatch but testing it out on my end that doesn't make a difference. Any other details about the layer that is misbehaving? Just to rule out other causes - what happens if you try 'Clip all layers'? Also changing the clip render options?

Comment: @she_weeds: Nothing all that special about the layer - It's a simple point layer imported from US GNIS. I've tried all the render options and that doesn't help, neither does the clip all layers. The only thing so far that I have been able to see in common is that it DOES clip the ArcGIS vector tile layers, but not points, polygons, etc. layers.